# Call library function in compile

Tags: bugs, librarylink

On the Wolfram official website, there is an [example](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/compiler-performance-enhancements/call-an-external-library-function-from-compile.html) of calling library function in a compiled function:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

fun=LibraryFunctionLoad[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"demo.dylib"}],"demo_I_I",{Integer},Integer];

c=Compile[{{x,_Integer}},fun[x],CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True,"InlineCompiledFunctions"->True},CompilationTarget->"C"];

CompilePrint@c

(*
    1 argument
    2 Integer registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    I0 = A1
    Result = I1

1   I1 = LibraryFunction[<>, demo_I_I, {Integer}, Integer][ I0]]
2   Return

*)
```

However, if I try it with my function (code at the end) with shared passing, the library function is not linked correctly, and a `MainEvaluate` is presented in the compiled code:

```
add1lib = CreateLibrary[add1src, "add1"];
add1 = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad[add1lib, "add1", {{Real, 1, "Shared"}}, "Void"];

f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{ls},
   ls = Table[i/1., {i, 1, n}];
   a[ls];
   ls
   ]]

CompilePrint@f

(*
.....       
10  V17T(R1)0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{n, lsCompile$1}, Block[{ls = lsCompile$1}, {a[ls], ls}]][ I0, T(R1)0]]
11  Return
*)
```

Here is a test of this function:

```
a = {1., 2.} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
add1[a]
a
(* {2., 3.} *)
```

Note that in my function, I use shared passing of argument, so that I can modify them inside the library function.

Question:

Why does it break in my case? How to make it work?

---

add1src

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}


DLLEXPORT int add1( WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {

    MTensor tx = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    double* x = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tx);

    mint N=*(libData->MTensor_getDimensions(tx));
    mint i;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) x[i]=x[i]+1.;

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because your function returns `Void` and for some reason `Compile` can't handle that.

If you cheat *Mathematica* and tell it that your function returns an `Integer`:

```
add1NonVoid =
    LibraryFunctionLoad[add1lib, "add1", {{Real, 1, "Shared"}}, Integer];

a = {1., 2.} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
add1NonVoid[a]
(* 0 *)
a
(* {2., 3.} *)
```

then it will be called directly, without `MainEvaluate`:

```
f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{ls},
        ls = Table[i/1., {i, 1, n}];
        add1NonVoid[ls];
        ls
    ],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
];
CompilePrint@f
(*
...
10  I3 = LibraryFunction[<>, add1, {{Real, 1, Shared}}, Integer][ T(R1)0]]
11  Return
*)

f[5]
(* {2., 3., 4., 5., 6.} *)
```

I don't really know what happens under the hood when *Mathematica* returns integer from function that really returns void, so I can't recommend doing something like this.

---

Handling of void in `Compile` is buggy not only in case of calling `LibraryFunction`, but also other `CompiledFunction`s.

Compiling following to virtual machine works fine:

```
returnNothing = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, lst + 1;];
Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    returnNothing[{1., 2.}];
    ,
    CompilationOptions -> {
        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True,
        "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False
    },
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
];
CompilePrint@%
(*
...
1   V17 = CompiledFunctionCall[ Hold[CompiledFunction[{lst}, lst + 1; , -CompiledCode-]][ T(R1)0]]
2   Return
*)
```

but you can't compile it to `"C"` (of course you could use `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` here and it would work, but that's not the point).

```
Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    returnNothing[{1., 2.}];
    ,
    CompilationOptions -> {
        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
        "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False
    },
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
];
(*
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in CCodeGenerator`Private`typeToVariable[Void]<>0_17. >>
...
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It surprises me that `Compile` can't handle `void` return. I would guess `void` return would be quite common. I'm wondering how they deal that inside wolfram. Would you consider that as a bug?

Comment: @xslittlegrass I was as surprised as you are. I'm not sure if this is a bug since it's all scarcely documented. And in documentation of `Compile` void is not mentioned in "The types handled by Compile", but I'd definitely like to see it fixed/changed/enhanced.

Comment: I think this is important, so I will tag it with bugs so maybe people will be aware of that. It took me a while to isolate this problem from my code.

Comment: I agree that it's a bug. When you get an unexpected `StringJoin::string` message by doing something that to all appearances should be perfectly allowable, I don't think we can describe it any other way.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ok, I've reported it: [CASE:3410009]

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sorry for distrub you. I would like to know: did you know how to deal with tensor in *LibraryLink*. Please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jusfV.png). Thanks:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG you are not really helping yourself by asking this in comments, especially on someone else's answer... however, you ought to either declare `P` as a pointer to a multidimensional array, or, just treat it as a one-dimensional array and do the pointer arithmetic manually.